# Postgres cast count(*) as integer?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postman

I have a simple query that returns count.

```
select count(*)
from table
wehre ....
```

I would like the count to return as an INTEGER and not a STRING. The default in Postgres seems to be String.

I have tried to do this:

```
select cast(count(*) as INTEGER)
....
```

but it's not working. The query runs, but the type of count is still a string. I've tried other ways unsuccessfully.

Is there a way to have the count return as an number instead of a string type?

EDIT:
As I checked the type of the result table in DataGrip it does show that the count return is of type "`count: Int`".

What threw me off is the result as returned in Postman.
The query select is this:

```
select person.age, count(*) from ....
```

When that query runs in the endpoint it's in, Postman shows this as result:
`[{"age":18, count: "45"}, ....]`

So, then I assumed that the count form Postgres was coming back as a string because the `age` (INTEGER type on the table) does return back as a number type and not a string. So, now I am confused as to why one column type is right, and the other is not (count...).

The query is run using Sequelize:

```
const result = await sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

and then return straight via:

```
res.status(200).json(result)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it: `select pg_typeof(count(*)) from cell_per; bigint`. How are you seeing/determining it is a string?

Comment: @S-Man is corect. Checking the type in DataGrip it shows "count: Int". I edited the question to explain more

Comment: My guess is `age` has a declared type in the model(?) for the table, whereas `count` is generated and cast as a string as a default type.

Comment: If Postman returns that as a string in the JSON response, then this is a problem in Postman - it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL PostgreSQL most certainly does **not** return `count(*)` as a string.

Answer (score 15):

As of now - you already know that `count` returns type `bigint` in Postgresql.

Regarding your Sequelize question. Sequelize uses [Node Postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) under the hood. Node Postgres comes [with support for types](https://node-postgres.com/features/types).

When your are explicitly querying for `person.age` - Node Postgres has a supported type parser for that type of field.

For `count(*)` - Node Postgres will return a string. In order to cast it to (big)int - so that Javascript recognizes it - you will have to create your own [Type Parser](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types)

> Let's say that you know you don't and wont ever have numbers greater
> than int4 in your database, but you're tired of recieving results from
> the COUNT(*) function as strings (because that function returns int8).
> You would do this:

```
var types = require('pg').types
types.setTypeParser(20, function(val) {
  return parseInt(val, 10)
})
```

Or cast it like this:

`SELECT count(*)::int`

If you are going down the custom type parser road - since Javascript now supports Bigint and you are confident that your Node version supports it - you may aswell try:

`types.setTypeParser(20, BigInt);`

Comment: very nice. I will test this out.

Comment: Thanks. `count(*)::int` was the simple solution for me.

Comment: For those who use the latter method (`BigInt`), if you use the big int on an object that you want to serialize, you will get an error like this: `TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt` . See [this](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-521460510) for an easy solution.

Answer (score 5):

[As the documentation states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> count ( * ) → bigint
>
> Computes the number of input rows.    Yes

`count` returns type `bigint`. Not a string type.